# How to listen for changed hidden attribute

Tags: lit-element

Whats the correct way to listen for a change on the hidden attribute in a Lit Element?

e.g. an element like this:

`<my-element ?hidden="${this.activeTab != 1}"></my-element>`

I tried to define `updated(changedProperties)` but this does not trigger for a change in hidden.

Note on the background of the question:
I am using leaflet in this element and it seems like i have to call `_onResize()` on my leaflet container element after i change the visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by simply adding the `@property({ type: Boolean}) hidden: boolean = false;`(Typescript) to my own Element class even if hidden is already defined as a property in LitElement. After that `updated` gets called on every change.